# Url renaming using .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Most are for redirections and removing file extensions or for dynamic urls.

The problem being I can't get a simple static url to rename

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^fileThathasalongname file.html
```

What I currently have `'mysite.co.uk/fileThathasalongname.html'`

What I want is `'mysite.co.uk/file/' while file = file.html`

using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FileIWantToChange.html FriendlyNamed.html
```

Using this gives me the error multiple Choices

+++++++++++++++++Edit+++++++++++++++++++++++++

Thought i'd add my final version for people to look at, it may help, the anwser below is correct.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}/ -d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^FriendlyNamed.html FileIWantToChange.html [L]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysire.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

all works a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see multiple issues going on. Firstly the regular expression is matched against the friendly URL the user types in. So you need to swap your friendly url and file path with each other. The friendly or "fake" name goes on the left while the url to redirect to silently goes on the right. Also make sure you've set the directory base to `/`. Finally it's good to add an `[L]` to enforce it to be the last rule in case anything in the same file tries to rewrite the path. Due note that other htaccess files lower down, depending on the files location, will also be checked even when enforcing the rule has the last rule. Also junk the options part completely. Give this a try:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^FriendlyNamed.html FileIWantToChange.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply, worked like a charm, I added in the options + multiview for use with 1and1 hosting. Thanks for expanding on it aswell you've explained alot to me there ;)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^fileThathasalongname.html file.html

Comment: Hi Parnas, I have tried this before with the same errors, I'm getting Multiple Choices what could be wrong?